# norm of the functional $T(f)=\int_0^2f(x)dx-\int_3^{10}f(x)dx $ on $ L^2[0,10]$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let

$L^2[0,10]=\{f:[0,10]\rightarrow R  | f $is Lebesgue measurable and $\int_0^{10} f^2(x)dx \lt \infty  \}  $ eqipped with the norm $|| f ||=\big(\int_0^{10} f^2(x)dx \big)^{1/2}  $ and $T$ be the linear functional on $L^2[0,10]$ given by

$T(f)=\int_0^2f(x)dx-\int_3^{10}f(x)dx $

Then $|| T || $=_________

I have no idea how to approach this problem .Where to use the fact that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable? Please help me with me useful hints. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Measurability of $f$ is needed to talk about the Lebesgue integral of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

*Suggestion*:

Find a function $g(x)\in L^2$ such that your functional has the form $\langle f,g\rangle$ (the usual inner product). There must be such a function by the Riesz representation theorem. The norm of the functional is then just the norm of $g$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Thanks sir for your valuable suggestion.The question now makes more sense to me.I hope to finish the answer now.

Comment: Did you mean Riesz representation theorem? Because the Riesz-Fischer theorem is usually about the completeness of $L^p$ (and appearantly a theorem about the $L^2$ convergence of fourier series, based on the Wikipedia)

Comment: @Botond..Well, completeness of $ L^p$  spaces is ensured by Riesz-Fischer Theorem and existence of $g$ is ensured by Riesz-Representation Theorem , if I am not wrong.

Comment: @uniquesolution..This is a late question to ask.I have been struggling to show that T is bounded functional for representation theorem to be applied.Everything else is clear to me . Please help with this little part  sir.

Comment: @Kishore The idea is to explicitly find $g$, and only afterwards deduce that $T$ is bounded. Not the other way round. Your struggles should be directed in thinking how can you represent $Tf$ in the form $\int_0^{10}f(x)g(x)\,dx$, where you know exactly what $g$ is.

Comment: @uniquesolution..$g(x)$ is a simple function with values 1,0 and -1 on $[0,2],(2,3) $and $[3,10]  $respectively which is measurable and square integrable. Then I think boundedness of T is ensured by Cauchy- Schwarz Inequality.Am I right, sir?